# Yii2 Url Html format

Tags: html, url, encode, yii2

Quick Question:

i use following code in my View Script to generate a link

```
<?=HTML::a("(".$player['player']->steam_id_32.")",['steam/','steamid'=>$player['player']->steam_id_32])?>
```

This is going to return following link

> /web/steam/STEAM_0%3A0%3A96553432

how can i have it return

> /web/steam/STEAM_0:0:96553432

i tried some thing but could not figure it out thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is by design. You can't really change this behavior, but you could use a workaround.

The code below first creates the url and then decodes it. Then create the link (`<a>`) with the previous created url.

```
$url = urldecode(Url::toRoute(['steam/', 'steamid' => 'aa:bb:cc']));
echo Html::a('title', $url);
```